# PostGIS shortest distance from point to point

Tags: postgis, proximity

I'm new to Spatial Databases and I'm trying to find the nearest point of a point.

In my application there is a google map and the user can click anywhere on it. The click executes a request to the server which should return the nearest point in the database from the point where the user clicked.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT point, strength
FROM signalstrengths 
ORDER BY st_distance(st_makepoint(:lng, :lat)::geography, point) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This query always returns one of two points, no matter where i click, although I have around 2k records in the database.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: shouldnt it be asc if you trying to find the closest point?

Comment: ST_ClosestPoint can be also used (depending on your postgis version) https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

Comment: @Mapperz not really, `ST_ClosestPoint` finds the nearest point on a plane, to another point, such that `ST_ClosestPoint(point1, point2)` will always return point1 because there is no other point to choose from. I would prefer it be called `ST_ClosestPlanarPoint` but you know.. =(

Comment: @ziggy yes you are right thanks, don't know what I've been thinking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @ziggy said in the comments,

> "shouldnt it be asc if you trying to find the closest point?"

Your code is not correct (reproduced below),

```
SELECT point, strength
FROM signalstrengths 
ORDER BY st_distance(st_makepoint(:lng, :lat)::geography, point) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

What you want is,

```
SELECT point, strength
FROM signalstrengths 
ORDER BY st_distance(st_makepoint(:lng, :lat)::geography, point)
LIMIT 1;
```

Notice no `DESC` so `ASC` is implied. That said, even that is *horrible*, what you **really want is [KNN.](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)** You don't care about the distance, you just want the nearest point. Do it the fast way with `<->`.

```
SELECT point, strength
FROM signalstrengths 
ORDER BY point <-> st_makepoint(:lng, :lat)::geography
LIMIT 1;
```

KNN will use a GIST index on `signalstrengths(point)` if available.

```
CREATE INDEX ON signalstrengths USING gist(point);
```

Comment: postgresql 9.5+ <-> returns true distances between geometries https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html

Comment: thanks alot <-> operator worked with index and also sped up my queries a lot